# JxBrowser doesnt work with the latest chromedriver

Tags: jxbrowser

chromedriver 2.40.565383 reports an error of: Chrome version must be >= 66.0.3359.0
JxBrowser is currently using 64.0.3282.24

Any idea when JxBrowser will be updated to a more recent version of Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

We already started migration to the new version of the Chromium engine. As soon as an updated build based on the new Chromium engine is available for download, I will let you know.